# showmessage.jar not found 404

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm new in Oracle Forms, i try to execute an application developped in Oracle Forms with Java Web Start, so this application need a jar file named "showmessage.jar", when i check the folder "$ORACLE_HOME/forms/java" i found the file but when i try to access to it via browser http://192.168.1.22:8888/forms/java/showmessage.jar i have an 404 error.

I tried to rename the jar file and i can access to it, i don't know why ?

If anyone had an idea about this issue, Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it on a windows or on a unix/linux server?
Or on your own system?

Comment: it's on linux system

Comment: Are the user owner rights correct? The HTTP server will try to read the file, has the user with which the HTTP server is started enough rights on the file?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, the http server has the rights to access to the file, if i change the name of the file, the http server bring me the file without problem but if the file name is "showmessage.jar" the server return 404 error !!

Comment: Then I think the server has in its cache that the file doesn't exists. Try rebooting the OHS

Comment: i tried to reboot the OHS and all services but the error persist

Answer (score 0):

In the rwserver.conf file, you can set what folders Forms (and Reports!) has access to.

[Configuring file access](http://dirknachbar.blogspot.com/2017/09/configure-oracle-reports-12c-122x-for.html)

This link describes the "write" access, but this is also how "read" access is configured (I haven't tried this with environment variables):

```
# Single Target Directory
      <folderAccess>
          <read>C:\oracle\forms\</read>
          <write>C:\oracle\forms</write>
      </folderAccess>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, but i'm on 11G and the problem is with Forms not Reports, and i have all access to the folder